# netbeans unable to copy context xml file from temp folder to tomee's localhost when deploy. FileNotFoundException(access denied)

Tags: java, netbeans, deployment, tomee-8

**netbeans unable to copy context `xml` file from `AppData\Local\Temp\` folder to `tomee`'s `conf\Catalina\localhost` when deploy.**

already tried：

```
deploy to tomee 7.0.X is fine but tomee 8.0.0 fail.
```

fatal error in `stderr.log`：

> 03-Oct-2019 16:31:22.358 fatal [http-nio-9200-exec-6]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.copy Error copying
>   [C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\context2716699461818377726.xml] to
>   [D:\Tomee\apache-tomee-plus-8.0.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\myApp.xml]
>     java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\context2716699461818377726.xml (Access
>   is denied.)       at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)         at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)        at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)      at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.copy(ExpandWar.java:276)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This problem only occurs when Tomee is running as a Windows service.
>   I tested version 7.0.4~8.0.0 to get the following conclusions.
>   The Tomee runs the service with the LocalSystem account before version 7.0.6.
>   Starting with version 7.0.6, the service is run with the LocalService account, so that the permissions are insufficient.
>   **The following two ways can solve the issue:**
>    - Give the LocalService account access to the directory `AppData\Local\Temp\`.
>    - Specifying the Tomee runs the service with the LocalSystem account when installing the service.
>     
>   `service install %serviceName% --service-user LocalSystem`